# Create adjacent buffers around grid points

Tags: qgis, buffer

I've a file of grid points (ERA5 meteorological info grids) and I'd like to convert the points to adjacent polygons so I can create nice maps from them.

The resolution of my grids is around 30 km x 30 km, however unfortunately it's not unique, neither in km, neither in degrees.

I could calculate distance of grid points in another program and add desired height & widths as new column to apply them as buffers' dimension, however I'd also be interested in a solution completely done in QGIS.

Sample data:
[image]

| location | lat | lon |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 38.6°N/27.8°E204.9m | 38.64167 | 27.77344 |
| 38.6°N/28.1°E357.3m | 38.64167 | 28.125 |
| 38.6°N/28.5°E462.3m | 38.64167 | 28.47656 |
| 38.6°N/28.8°E619.0m | 38.64167 | 28.82812 |
| 38.4°N/27.8°E630.4m | 38.36064 | 27.77344 |
| 38.4°N/28.1°E795.8m | 38.36064 | 28.125 |
| 38.4°N/28.5°E651.6m | 38.36064 | 28.47656 |
| 38.4°N/28.8°E663.0m | 38.36064 | 28.82812 |
| 38.1°N/27.7°E328.0m | 38.07961 | 27.66667 |
| 38.1°N/28.0°E605.1m | 38.07961 | 28 |
| 38.1°N/28.3°E747.2m | 38.07961 | 28.33333 |
| 38.1°N/28.7°E741.9m | 38.07961 | 28.66667 |
| 37.8°N/27.7°E176.4m | 37.79858 | 27.66667 |
| 37.8°N/28.0°E188.5m | 37.79858 | 28 |
| 37.8°N/28.3°E437.6m | 37.79858 | 28.33333 |
| 37.8°N/28.7°E655.0m | 37.79858 | 28.66667 |

Desired output (Example from another file with 0.1 x 0.1 degree resolution):
[image]

Comment: @Babel Ideally I'd like to get rectangles, but these also look nice, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If any kind of polygon, not just rectangles, is OK for you, than the easiest way is to simply create voronoi polygons, using `Menu Vector / Geometry Tools / Voronoi polygons`. See this example, based on the points you provided in your question, including a value of 20 for `Buffer region (% of extent)`:

[image]

You could also apply `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Oriented minimum bounding box` to get rectangles - they will overlap, however:

[image]